# Generate and upload a file to s3 with flask

Tags: python, flask, amazon-s3

is it possible to generate and upload a file to s3?

I have tried to implement this flask application, but it dies with this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/report.csv'
```

This is my app.py:

```
@app.route("/upload/<string:START_REPORT>/<string:STOP_REPORT>/<string:IDS>/", methods=['POST'])
def upload(START_REPORT, STOP_REPORT, IDS):
    """
    Function to upload a file to an S3 bucket
    """
    os.environ["START_REPORT"] = START_REPORT
    os.environ["STOP_REPORT"] = STOP_REPORT
    os.environ["IDS"] = IDS
    dft, filename = report_visit.report() 
    dft.to_csv(filename, index=False) # <-- Error here
    object_name = filename
    s3_client = boto3.client(
        "s3",
        region_name='eu-west-1',
        endpoint_url="url",
        aws_access_key_id="key",
        aws_secret_access_key="key"
    )
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        response = s3_client.upload_fileobj(f, app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], f.filename)
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run (debug=True, port='8080', host='127.0.0.1')
```

where filename is 'report.csv'

This is the post request I do with postman:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/upload/2020_2_10_0_0_0_0/2020_2_10_1_0_0_0/138/
```

It would be hard I think for me to give a proper working example, but any suggestion are welcome

the function `report_visit.report()` returns a pandas dataframe and the name of the filename

Any suggestion would be appreciated, thanks

Matteo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to write into the root directory '/'. So, your app needs root permissions (run with sudo; highly not recommended by security thoughts) or specify some path to tmp folder to store those files there(looks like you want to use "./report.csv" - file will be created into working directory).

Comment: the tmp folder must be on the local computer or on the s3 server?

Comment: @MatteoPeluso defenitely on computer which produces this file